# How do integrate the windows live msn in vb.net application?

Tags: vb.net

How do integrate the windows live msn in vb.net?

I will try it. But I can't do it. How do integrate msn (Adds to sound,picture,video etc)

in vb.net forms application.You think any idea please help for me.

Comment: maybe because of 'P'lease 'h'el'p' ???

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim objMSN As New MessengerAPI.Messenger
Dim chlContacts As New CheckedListBox
 
Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
     Dim msncontact As MessengerAPI.IMessengerContact
     Dim msncontacts As MessengerAPI.IMessengerContacts = objMSN.MyContacts

     ' Get rid of anything in the list.
     lsvUser.Items.Clear()

     ' Loop through all the contacts and add the SigninName to the list.
     For Each msncontact In msncontacts
        Dim lv As ListViewItem = lsvUser.Items.Add(msncontact.SigninName, IIf(msncontact.Status = 2, 0, 1))
        lv.SubItems.Add(IIf(msncontact.Status = 2, "On-Line", "Off-Line"))
     Next
End Sub
```